# Only display an image when completely loaded without JavaScript

Tags: html, css

How can I display an image when it's completely loaded without using plugins or JavaScript? Is there a way to do this in pure CSS3/HTML5?

Answer (score 1):

You could `base64`-encode your pictures and embed them in your HTML:

```
<img src="data:image/png;base64,{REPLACE_THIS_WITH_YOUR_BASE64_STRING}">
```

A pure CSS3 / HTML5-solution is not available.

Answer (score 0):

What about using css keyframes and a delay. Its not perfect because you cannot detect the page load using just css or html you need js

```
img {
-webkit-animation: fadein 1s 3s forwards;
   -moz-animation: fadein 1s 3s forwards;
    -ms-animation: fadein 1s 3s forwards;
     -o-animation: fadein 1s 3s forwards;
        animation: fadein 1s 3s forwards;
}

@keyframes fadein {
    from { opacity: 0; }
    to   { opacity: 1; }
}
@-moz-keyframes fadein {
    from { opacity: 0; }
    to   { opacity: 1; }
}
@-webkit-keyframes fadein {
    from { opacity: 0; }
    to   { opacity: 1; }
}
@-ms-keyframes fadein {
    from { opacity: 0; }
    to   { opacity: 1; }
}
@-o-keyframes fadein {
    from { opacity: 0; }
    to   { opacity: 1; }
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/matt3224/Bp9v7/